# Get most frequent latitude-longitude set

Tags: solr

I have many documents which have `latitude` and `longitude` fields. I want to search over these documents and search the **most frequent** `(latitude, longitude)` pairs that occur.

Also I expect minor errors; eg `(1.1121, 35.8788)` and `(1.1121, 35.8789)` but the searches must be robust enough to handle that.

Comment: Why do you want to use Solr for this? I would just do one pass, store the pairs in a hashtable and keep counts.

Comment: The data happens to be persisted in Solr. Yes, using a count works too

Comment: I suppose you could use the group collapsing functionality but it's probably better to just query the whole index and write your own code on the other end to count.